# "make test" output errors command after installed preCICE on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos7, hpc

I get an error the following after run make test command in preCICE on Centos 7. Did anyone encounter this problem?

Thank you...

**cmake parameters when building**

```
 cmake3 .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DMPI=ON 
-DMPIEXEC_EXECUTABLE=/opt/ohpc/pub/mpi/openmpi3-gnu8/3.1.4/bin/mpiexec 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt $PRECICE_ROOT
```

```
[root@headnode build]# make test 

Running tests...
Test project /opt/precice-1.6.1/build
    Start 1: precice.Base
1/4 Test #1: precice.Base .....................***Failed    0.01 sec
    Start 2: precice.MPI_Ports 
2/4 Test #2: precice.MPI_Ports ................***Failed    0.01 sec
    Start 3: precice.PetRBFParallel
3/4 Test #3: precice.PetRBFParallel ...........***Failed    0.01 sec
    Start 4: precice.NoMPI
4/4 Test #4: precice.NoMPI ....................   Passed    4.09 sec

25% tests passed, 3 tests failed out of 4

Label Time Summary:
canfail    =   0.02 sec*proc (2 tests)

Total Test time (real) =   4.14 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - precice.Base (Failed)
      2 - precice.MPI_Ports (Failed)
      3 - precice.PetRBFParallel (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Before running test as root enter following :

export OMPI_ALLOW_RUN_AS_ROOT_CONFIRM=1
export OMPI_ALLOW_RUN_AS_ROOT=1